# What is the name of the artstyle used in so many anime portraying certain emotions/actions of rage?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter, fire-force

I see this art style in certain frames of animes when a character is consumed by rage or when an action like a fire occurs. This is common in manga and anime like *Fire Force*, or Gon's rage scene.

[image] [image]

I would like to look at more works like this as a reference, but I can't seem to find the name of the art style.

Comment: Fire Force being literally a manga that has fire as it central trope doesn't seem a fitting example, but the question has merit. Just to know, do you refer to just the "extreme rage" style, usually black&white scene or any form of "determination fire"? For example, do you consider flame eyes a sub-case of this trope? It **may** be tied to the  Yamato-damashii.

Answer (score 2):

Tsumi-e in negative (whites appear blacks, and darks to lights) for impact frames. Maybe I'm stating the obvious here.